# READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level behavior on more than one transaction

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure to update a table, and i set the isolation level to READ UNCOMMITTED. In this sp i set the comment count (CommentCount+=1). If more than one user call this sp at the same time, is it possible that comment count increase less than number of user that added comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server still acquires locks on updated rows in the `READ UNCOMMITTED` isolation level. An `UPDATE` statement like this will not miss increments when executed by multiple `READ UNCOMMITTED` sessions concurrently:

```
UPDATE dbo.Post
SET CommentCount += 1
WHERE PostID = @PostID;
```

Here's a trace of locks by this statement, updating by a clustered primary key on PostID. The exclusive lock will block other concurrent updates to the row.

```
+---------------+----+--------------+----------+--+
| Lock:Acquired | 58 | 5 - OBJECT   | 8 - IX   |  |
| Lock:Acquired | 58 | 6 - PAGE     | 8 - IX   |  |
| Lock:Acquired | 58 | 7 - KEY      | 5 - X    |  |
| Lock:Released | 58 | 7 - KEY      | 0 - NULL |  |
| Lock:Released | 58 | 6 - PAGE     | 0 - NULL |  |
| Lock:Released | 58 | 7 - KEY      | 5 - X    |  |
| Lock:Released | 58 | 6 - PAGE     | 8 - IX   |  |
| Lock:Released | 58 | 5 - OBJECT   | 8 - IX   |  |
+---------------+----+--------------+----------+--+
```

And here's a trace where the row is located using a non-clustered primary key index. The update lock on the non-clustered key will serialize other update statements for the same key and the exclusive lock on the clustered key will block other data modifications.

```
+---------------+----+------------+----------+--+
| Lock:Acquired | 58 | 5 - OBJECT | 8 - IX   |  |
| Lock:Acquired | 58 | 6 - PAGE   | 7 - IU   |  |
| Lock:Acquired | 58 | 7 - KEY    | 4 - U    |  |
| Lock:Acquired | 58 | 6 - PAGE   | 7 - IU   |  |
| Lock:Acquired | 58 | 7 - KEY    | 4 - U    |  |
| Lock:Acquired | 58 | 6 - PAGE   | 8 - IX   |  |
| Lock:Acquired | 58 | 7 - KEY    | 5 - X    |  |
| Lock:Released | 58 | 7 - KEY    | 0 - NULL |  |
| Lock:Released | 58 | 6 - PAGE   | 0 - NULL |  |
| Lock:Released | 58 | 7 - KEY    | 4 - U    |  |
| Lock:Released | 58 | 6 - PAGE   | 7 - IU   |  |
| Lock:Released | 58 | 7 - KEY    | 5 - X    |  |
| Lock:Released | 58 | 6 - PAGE   | 8 - IX   |  |
| Lock:Released | 58 | 5 - OBJECT | 8 - IX   |  |
+---------------+----+------------+----------+--+
```